# Radio Button Selection driving div visibility with JS not ONCLICK

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, bootstrap-5

I have some html code that works partially. I a trying to get some text inputs to show depending on a radio button selection. I have it working that when a radio button is pressed it does hide the other options but on the first load of the screen all 3 options are displayed. I, assuming its because the function is called when clicked and the checked option for the first radio button doesn't constitute as a click. I tried to make a onload event listentner that would only show in the state that I first requested but that didnt work.
here is my code

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') %>
    <h1>New Part</h1>
    <form action="/parts" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form">
        <div>
            <label class="form-label" for="partnum">Part Number</label>
            <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="part[partnum]"  id="partnum" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="form-label" for="description">Part  Description</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="part[description]"   id="description" required>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="part[type]" id="btnradio1" value="Purchased" autocomplete="off"  onclick="show1()" checked >
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Purchased</label>
          
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="part[type]" id="btnradio2" value="Assembly" autocomplete="off" onclick="show2()">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Assembly</label>
          
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="part[type]" id="btnradio3" value="Machined" autocomplete="off" onclick="show3()">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Machined</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1 id="test1">Test 1</h1> 
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1 id="test2" >Test 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="machined">
            <h1 id="test3" >Test 3</h1>
            <div>
                <label class="form-label" for="material">Material</label>
                <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="part[material]"  id="material" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div><button>Add  Part</button></div>    
    </form>
    <a href="/parts">Back to your Parts</a>

    <script>  
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('test1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('test2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('machined').style.display ='none';
}
function show2(){
  document.getElementById('test1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('test2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('machined').style.display ='none';
}
function show3(){
  document.getElementById('test1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('test2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('machined').style.display ='block';
}
  
    </script>
```

Comment: Absolute easiest would be just to specify `style="display: none"` in the markup for the `test2` and `test3` elements (i.e. the style that they would have if `show1()` were called). Does that help?

Comment: Yes!! that worked. would this be a quote on quote right way to do it? But that did work. Thank you

Comment: It depends! If this were a "one and done" kinda deal, I'd just do it like this and get on with life. If there was more involved, I would look into creating separate CSS classes for e.g. `selected-test1`, `selected-test2`, `selected-machined` which control the visibility of the various sub-forms, then just have a `show(which)` click handler and so on. I can type that up as an answer if you like.

Comment: If you would not mind that would be appreciated I am most likely going to use these options in other pages. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call each of the sections that needs to be conditionally shown/hidden a "subform". You can add a CSS class for each subform, e.g.:

```html
  <div class="subform1">
    <h1 id="test1">Test 1</h1>
  </div>
```

You can then introduce CSS rules to hide all subforms except for the one corresponding to the currently selected option. A good way to keep track of that selection so that CSS can see it is as a data attribute on an element that contains all your options, for instance the `<form>`. Your initial value for this will determine the initially-visible subform:

```html
<form data-selection="1" id="part-number" class="subform-group" ...>
  <!-- Now we can style anything inside here based on .subform-group[data-selection] -->
</form>
```

... and the corresponding styles ...

```css
/* Hide .subform1 unless it's currently selected */
.subform1 { display: none; }
.subform-group[data-selection="1"] .subform1 { display: block; }
```

To tie it together, we can make a JS function to update the data attribute. Maybe you'll have multiple groups of subforms on a page (or even within a single form) so it's useful to identify which selection you're updating:

```js
    function show(subformGroupId, selection) {
      document.getElementById(subformGroupId).setAttribute("data-selection", selection);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="radio" value="Purchased" onclick="show('part-number', 1)" checked>
    <input type="radio" value="Assembly"  onclick="show('part-number', 2)">
    <input type="radio" value="Machined"  onclick="show('part-number', 3)">
```

If you need extra options, you can add extra `subform` CSS classes; if you need multiple groups of subforms you can add them, being sure to use a separate HTML element with a unique `id` to contain all of the subforms.

See the complete snippet for a working example.

```js
function show(subformGroupId, selection) {
  document.getElementById(subformGroupId).setAttribute("data-selection", selection);
}
```

```css
.subform1,
.subform2,
.subform3,
.subform4  /* add extra subforms as needed ... */
{
  display: none;  /* Hide all forms by default */
}

.subform-group[data-selection="1"] .subform1,
.subform-group[data-selection="2"] .subform2,
.subform-group[data-selection="3"] .subform3,
.subform-group[data-selection="4"] .subform4  /* add extra subforms as needed ... */
{
  display: block;  /* Display the form matching the selected option */
}
```

```html
<h1>New Part</h1>

<form action="/parts" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form subform-group" id="part-number" data-selection="1">
  <div>
    <label class="form-label" for="partnum">Part Number</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="part[partnum]" id="partnum" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="form-label" for="description">Part  Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="part[description]" id="description" required>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="part[type]" id="btnradio1" value="Purchased" autocomplete="off" onclick="show('part-number', 1)" checked>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Purchased</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="part[type]" id="btnradio2" value="Assembly" autocomplete="off" onclick="show('part-number', 2)">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Assembly</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="part[type]" id="btnradio3" value="Machined" autocomplete="off" onclick="show('part-number', 3)">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Machined</label>
  </div>
  <div class="subform1">
    <h1 id="test1">Test 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="subform2">
    <h1 id="test2">Test 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="subform3" id="machined">
    <h1 id="test3">Test 3</h1>
    <div>
      <label class="form-label" for="material">Material</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="part[material]" id="material" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><button>Add  Part</button></div>
</form>
<a href="/parts">Back to your Parts</a>
```